# ImportError: No module named mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi4py

I am brand new to parallel computing and I'm trying to set up a small cluster of Raspberry Pi's to fiddle around with. Whenever I went to install `mpi4py`,  I used `pip3 install mpi4py` but I am still getting the following error when I try to run a simple test script. I am able to use `mpiexec` with a Hello World script that prints "Hello" for every core in the cluster.

Hardware is a cluster Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Rasbian Lite

test.py:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

print("Test")
```

This is the readout that I am getting from the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: No module named mpi4py
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running the script? Is it with the version of `python` that reads from the library that `pip3` installs to?

Comment: I always use `python -m pip install` to make sure packages end up in the right `python` installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python beginner - No module named 'mpi4py'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032897/python-beginner-no-module-named-mpi4py)

Comment: try `python -m pip install mpi4py`

Comment: @chepner I am running the script with ```mpiexec -hostlist nodes_ips python test.py```

When I try to run ```python -m pip install mpi4py```, I am getting an error that there is not module named 'pip'

Comment: @BuddyBob I tried to install using that but it didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and frankly I feel a little silly now. I wasn't aware that Debian for Raspberry Pi comes preinstalled with both Python 2 and Python 3, so I have run to `mpiexec -hostlist nodes_ips python3 test.py` instead.

Comment: Maybe it's Python and distros which are a bit silly here. But yes you used `pip3` explicitly so that goes with explicit `python3`. Luckily the painful 2-> 3 transition is I guess pretty much done finally now, and maybe some time before year 3000 there's only 3 and that also as default everywhere (py 3 project was called Python 3000 initially).